# Dirac equation for neutrinos

Tags: fermions, dirac-equation, neutrinos, majorana-fermions

Neutrinos are described by spinors. But they don't have a defined mass (they are in a superposition). How can I write the Dirac (Majorana) equation for neutrinos?

Maybe

$$i \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} \nu = \sum U_j m_j \nu ~? $$

Comment: I think it's the Weyl equation.

Comment: But Weyl's equation is for massless particles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick to the simplest, lepton number conserving case, hence Dirac; ignoring interaction terms, they are described by three decoupled Drac equations,
$$i{\not} \partial \psi_j = m_j \psi_j,$$ given in all reviews. The index *j* ranges from 1,2,3, probably L, M, H, lightest, middle, heaviest.

The PMNS matrix mixes these three into "convenience linear combinations" coupling to the *e, μ, τ* charged leptons (confusingly labelled "flavor basis eigenstates"). Quarks do that, too.

What *could* be the problem?